# Stoping a back-forward div animation by limiting the pixels?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I'm new to jQuery and I just had this assignment which consisted in creating a kind of slider using a div with `abosolute` positioning.

I just created a div `gallery` containing 4 pictures in it. `gallery` (absolute position) is inside another div (position relative) which has the same size than that of the pictures. And then I have two buttons "back" and "forward".

This is the code I have thus far:

```
$("document").ready(function() {
    $("#back").click(function() {
        $("#gallery").animate({"left": "+=104px"}, "slow");
    });

    $("#forward").click(function() {
        $("#gallery").animate({"left": "-=104px"}, "slow");
    });
});
```

It's pretty simple but it works just fine.

So, every time I click on either "back" or "forward", `gallery` moves by increasing or decreasing it's left position the exact amount of pixels the width of each photo inside `gallery`.

The problem is that it keeps doing so and I want it implemented so that once it reaches either the last photo or the first one, the animation stops.

I understand that there should be a condition, an `if` statement that said something like "if it increases/decreases this much (416 px for instance as I just have 4 pictures) stop the animation".

I tried many options and I've been searching all week long, but I guess that there must be some problem with the syntax or whatever I don't get. Can the community help me implement this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Add a variable that keeps track of the current slide.

```
$("document").ready(function(){
    var counter = 1;

    $("#back").click(function() {
        if( counter > 1 ) {
            $("#gallery").animate({"left": "+=104px"}, "slow");
            counter--;
        }
    });
    $("#forward").click(function(){
        if( counter < 4 ) {
            $("#gallery").animate({"left": "-=104px"}, "slow");
            counter++;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `left` of `#gallery`, or store a variable count in `#gallery`
The way to read a CSS property is [css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)